# Correct formula, wrong program... C programming loops

Tags: c, loops, math, formula, exponential

I need to know what am I missing here? It is seemingly very trivial but at the same time is kinda stupid maybe idk. The formula is given in the comments. I need to get the program correct. At the moment it is giving a reeeaaallllyyyy high output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main ()
{
// M(n)=p(k^n+k^n-1+.....+k^2+k)
// k=(1+r/100)^d
float p, k, r, d, n, m, t, temp, sum;
int i, j;
clrscr();
sum = 0;
d=20;
temp = 1;
printf ("\nEnter Principle per month ");
scanf ("%f", &p);
printf ("\nEnter number of months");
scanf ("%f", &n);
printf ("\nEnter rate per day");
scanf ("%f", &r);
k = 1;
t = (1 + (r / 100));
for (j = 0; j < d; j++)
   {
     k = k * t;
   }

for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    temp = temp * k;
    sum = sum + temp;
  }
m = p * sum;
printf ("\nValue after %f months is %f", n, m);

getch();
 }
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of input, expected output, obtained output?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the input you use, the actual output you get and the expected output. If it's not obviously clear explain what's wrong with the actual output. You might want to check intermediate results either by running your program in a debugger or by printing the values. (e.g. `t`, `k`, `temp`, `sum`). Maybe the precision of `float` is not sufficient for your task. You could try to use `double` instead.

Comment: The body of the loop `for (j = 0; j++; j < d) { k = k * t;}` will execute 0 times, regardless of the value of `d`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes actually, the code and the formula were right, just the order for the loop decl was wrong, thanks for the help...

Answer (score 3):

For one thing (no pun intended), your `for`s are wrong:

```
for (i = 1; i++; i <= n)
```

It should be initialization -> condition -> increment, not what you wrote.

Also your formula sums from `k^n` to `k^(2+k)`, while your code, once corrected, sums from `k^n` to `k^1`.

Comment: There we go, as I mentioned in the OP, very silly indeed, working just fine right now. Muchas Gracias...